# Replicating cosine/sine graph, but with reflections?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

[Replicating a cosine graph with sine, given transformations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315218/replicating-a-cosine-graph-with-sine-given-transformations)

This is an extension question of my previous post.

Say I have an equation like $y = 7 \cos(0.96(x-3)) + 11$.

How would I find the sine equivalent that lines exactly with it? I thought that $\sin$ and $\cos$ differ only by a phase shift of $\displaystyle -\frac{\pi}{2}$, when do I need to use reflections?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$A * \sin( B * x - C ) + D$

A = amplitude

B = Period,  usually given as pi/B

C = phase shift (or horizontal offset if you prefer)

D = vertical offset

Since you are only changing the horizontal to correctly duplicate sine in cosine or vice versa, the ONLY thing that should change is the phase shift, which is $\pm \pi/2$ to cause it to align with the opposite function.

addendum
A & B are assumed to be 1 if not otherwise given
C & D are assumed to be 0 if not otherwise given

Comment: apologies, the bracketing was wrong, fixed now

Comment: That works. It can easily be confirmed algebraically, or one can play with the graphs [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rlx5yojxz3). OP could easily convert their formula to this form perform the phase shift, and if they really must have the answer in their original form they can convert it back. Personally I prefer it the way you have shown it.

Comment: I think OP may be confusing (X -3) as being (X-C) when the whole thing should be X since it is being multiplied by 0.96. OPs completed correction should look like $7sin(0.96(x-3)+pi/2)$ and **NOT** $7sin(0.96(x-3+pi/2))$

Answer (score 0):

what about 
$$\begin{align} y & = 7 \cos(0.96(x-3)) + 11 \\
&= 7 \sin(\pi/2 + 0.96(x-3)) + 11\\
& = 7\sin(0.96(x - 3 + \pi/(2 \times 0.96)) + 11\\
&= 7 \sin(0.96(x- 1.3637) + 11?
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hmm, I don't get your steps. How did you do this? My logic was to add 6.5/4 since that is a "quarter of the period" here and pi/2 is a quarter of the standard 2pi period.

Comment: @user164403.  $\sin(t+\pi/2) = \cos t$  is an identity, meaning is true for all $t.$  that is what i used.

Comment: What would you do if the question asked for the amplitude to be negative for sin?

Comment: @user164403,  i will add a $\pi$ to the argument of $\sin$ and negate the amplitude.

Comment: Hmm, I tried doing that. I got -7sin(0.96(x+0.27)) + 11, but it gives me a much more shifted graph. What did I do wrong? I did -7sin(0.96(x-3) + pi)) + 11, and brought the pi back into the brackets getting phase shift of 0.27.